# If damaged by another player's Acid Attack, can I cede Tokyo?

Tags: king-of-tokyo

If I'm in Tokyo, and a player outside of Tokyo has Acid Attack, they will do one damage to me on their turn (even without rolling a claw). But will that damage from Acid Attack allow me to leave Tokyo (forcing the other play into Tokyo)?

Acid Attack reads

> Deal 1 extra damage each turn (even if you don't otherwise attack).

Answer (score 7):

In general, damage from cards are not considered attacks. For Acid Attack specifically, a search of the net shows the unanimous result that Acid Attack is not considered an attack. Since it's not an attack, you do not have the option of ceding.

Comment: The sites I skimmed had a lot of discussion before they came to a conclusion. Has there been ruling at a tournament or errata from the publisher?

Comment: Like I said, it's well known that damage from cards are not attacks. I did not find any official post that contradicts that for this card, meaning the only official rules I could find says it's not an attack. And every single post I've seen agrees.

Comment: Maybe a link to some of these unanimous posts?

Comment: Can't right now but simply searched for King of Tokyo Acid Attack